# How to do color overlay between errorbar and bar in a bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have a bar chart with errorbars, and I want to use the same color for both bar and errorbar. However, this would mean that I could not see the bottom part of the errorbar.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

my_df <- 
  tibble::tribble(~response, ~estimate, ~lower_ci, ~upper_ci,
                  "little_bit", 0.353477, 0.255625, 0.451747,
                  "no", 0.307639, 0.250436, 0.375393,
                  "very", 0.338883, 0.301007, 0.37572310)

## compare this:
ggplot(my_df, aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.9, fill = "#6EB3FF") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                width = 0.1, size = 3.5)

## with this:
ggplot(my_df, aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.9, fill = "#6EB3FF") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                width = 0.1, size = 3.5, color = "#6EB3FF")
```

[image: from_to]

---

### My visual idea is to use overlay

[image: overlay]

[image: gif]

Is there a way to achieve such overlay using `ggplot`?

Comment: You could use `alpha` to set the opacity, e.g. add `alpha = .7` to your geoms.

Comment: @stefan, can I set `alpha` for `geom_errorbar()` rather than for `geom_bar()`?

Comment: @Emman It won't do much without changing the color brightness first (see my answer). Or, you add alpha to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple alpha would do.

Note you technically *have* different colors. Another option would be to use color modifying packages such as `shades` or `colorspaces`. See one option with `colorspaces` below. `shades` is cool when you want to change entire palettes.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

my_df <- 
  tibble::tribble(~response, ~estimate, ~lower_ci, ~upper_ci,
                  "little_bit", 0.353477, 0.255625, 0.451747,
                  "no", 0.307639, 0.250436, 0.375393,
                  "very", 0.338883, 0.301007, 0.37572310)

# super easy, just make the bars mor transparent - not quite your desired look
ggplot(my_df, aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.9, fill = "#6EB3FF", alpha  = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                width = 0.1, size = 3.5,color = "#6EB3FF")
```

[image]

```r
## darkening the color, and adding some alpha for your desired effect
ggplot(my_df, aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.9, fill = "#6EB3FF") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                width = 0.1, size = 3.5, 
                color = colorspace::darken("#6EB3FF"), alpha  = 0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: ((: Yep. We posted almost at the same time. Interesting second option. Maybe I find some time in the holidays to have a closer look at the colorspace pkg.

Comment: @Tjebo, thank you! The first option is exactly what I'm looking for, just reversed :) It is the errorbar that I want to tweak its opacity, rather than the bar itself. Can this be achieved?

Comment: See my comment above. Technically, alpha makes your color "lighter", so without changing *both* alphas you would not be able to get the overlying error bars "darker"

Comment: But then. is it even possible to achieve the same hue on both the top of the errorbar and the bar, as shown in the question?

Comment: @Emman if you give the same alpha, they would have the same appearance. yes. if you don’t want alpha this would get very hacky. you would need to create two separat segments for that. Not sure this would be worth the effort

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you should draw the bottom-half of the error bars a second time with a slightly darker color.

```
ggplot(my_df, aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.9, fill = "#6EB3FF") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                width = 0.1, size = 3.5, color = "#6EB3FF") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = estimate-0.004),
                width = 0.1, size = 3.5, color="#3ba8ff")
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about that too. One limitation with such approach is generalizability over colors. Although here I used a single color for all bars, it's pretty common to have different color for each bar, or simply having different sets of colors. Needing to find a darker color for the bottom segment in each case makes such solution non-practical. Can you think of a "rule" that will allow automation?

Comment: You can define a vector of named colors as a choice for users, say, `color1 <- c("green1","red1","blue1","purple1","steelblue1")`. Then use a slightly darker color for the bottom-half of the error-bar as `color3 <- c("green3","red3","blue3","purple3","steelblue3")`.  You should define large number of colors.

Comment: @Emman try to think outside single boxes! Combine YBS and my answer and you'll have the solution. I.e.., you can use the shades packages to darken/brigthen entire palettes. No need to manually specify colors. Simple.

Comment: @Tjebo, good idea.  I agree that there is no need to define colors. Just use alpha = 0.7 for the first two calls.